# Is it possible to use GetRecords saved in Record Collection variable as filter value for another GetRecords

Tags: visual-workflow, filters

Let's say there is need to retrieve Users with particular Profiles. Of course we shouldn't use Ids and we got Record Collection with Ids according to Profiles Names. Can we somehow use this variable in another GetRecords as filter? It's worth noting that it might be more than one profile we need to process

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an equivalent to something like SOQL's `IN` in Flows. As an alternative, you could add a formula field on User to pull Profile Name in and then filter on that in the Get Node for Users.

Comment: It's not possible to create any new fields

Comment: SOQL `IN` operator added in Winter 23